# How do you get the URL of a tab that has just been CLOSED in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Should be straight-forward, right? We have the following listener at our disposal.

chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function (tabId, removeinfo))

tabId won't be valid anymore though since that tab has been removed. That leaves us with the removeinfo object, but the chrome documentation does not indicate what properties it contains. I am a javascript newbie so I have no idea if there is a way to get the properties through some kind of reflection process.

Any ideas? I've tried around 50 google searches so far.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(removeInfo)` and looking to see what it contains?

Comment: So it's a bit more than 5 years after this question was asked and I don't think anything has changed with this listener :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you want to poke through JS object contents, you can just spit it out to the console with `console.log(thing)` or `console.debug(thing)`.  The console opens with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, or <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on Mac.

Having done that, however, I can tell you that the `removeInfo` object doesn't have the info you need.  It's kind of a pain, but you'll have to add listeners to onCreated and onUpdated as well in order to keep track of the tabID-to-URL mapping using some global object as a hashtable, and then use the tabID on that object to retrieve the URL.  Note that these events require the `tabs` permission.  (More info here: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html)

If you can describe your use case and make a case for changing the API, I'd suggest opening a ticket at http://new.crbug.com.

Comment: thanks! im shocked that they would not have this obviously useful data in there, but i can now build what i need thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 6):

`removeInfo` in [onRemoved](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onRemoved) is a object that contains a single boolean value. It should look like this `{ isWindowClosing: false }`.

You will have to maintain an array of URLs as tabs with the [onUpdated](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) event. If the URL is present save it into an array and when an `onRemoved` event triggers you will have the URL saved.

```
var urls = [];
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.url) {
    urls[tabId] = changeInfo.url;
  }
});
```

When you want the URL of a tab that just closed you can use `var url = urls[tabId];`

Comment: thanks! gave you an upvote. gave the accepted answer to the other guy as the answers were almost identical but he had less reputation so needs them more :). i can finally get this done.